# A strange path to the folder

Tags: directory, find, paths

I have a folder called `DAT` on the desktop. I am not sure what I did the folder disappeared. Using find command `find / -name DAT 2>/dev/null`. This is the output `/home/t-gang/  /DL4PL`. I mean what is this path I could not even `cd` to. How can I find my folder?

Comment: Is `DL4PL` the folder renamed or the content of the folder (`DAT`)?

Comment: That output doesn't make sense. `find / -name DAT` cannot produce matches that don't have the name `DAT`. Are you sure this is what the command output was?

Answer (score 1):

To access path or file, which name contains special characters, we must quote these characters:

- Single character's quotation with backslash, that will quote only the symbol next to it:

  ```
  cd /home/t-gang/\ \ /DL4PL
  ```

  or, when you are in the home directory:

  ```
  ~$ cd \ \ /DL4PL
  ```
- Multiple character's quotation with single quotes<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/6543935)</sup>, that will quote the entire string:

  ```
  cd '/home/t-gang/  /DL4PL'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  ~$ cd '  /DL4PL'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  cd /home/t-gang/'  '/DL4PL
  ```

  etc.