# using '&' in a directory name

Tags: command-line, bash

i have a directory name with **ISO&Emulator** having some Important Files. and this directory is in different partition, and partition not showing in my FileManager(Nautilus). so i mount my partition and access it from terminal, but i can't get into directory because of its **name**.

when i tried to change directory:

```
cd ISO&Emulator
```

result:

```
[1] 1635
bash: Emulator: command not found
bash: cd: ISO: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 1
```

its taking directory name as a command.
any ways for access this directory from terminal?

how to fix this?

Comment: `cd 'ISO&Emulator'`

Comment: It is a good idea to **avoid** (remove if already there) **special characters in directory names and file names**. There are workarounds, but these characters can cause a lot of extra problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should quote the file or directory name, that contains special characters, when you using it:

```
cd 'ISO&Emulator'
```

```bsh
cd "ISO&Emulator"
```

Or escape (or quote) just the special character:

```bsh
cd ISO\&Emulator    
cd ISO'&'Emulator  
cd ISO"&"Emulator
```

In most cases you can use the auto-completion function:

```
cd ISOTab ↹
```

- Recently I found a nice answer, provided by @MartinThornton, that describes how to bind <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to [Select a particular result from completion suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707202/select-a-particular-result-from-completion-suggestions).
- See also: [How to make tab completion append slash for directory symlinks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900923/how-to-make-tab-completion-append-slash-for-directory-symlinks)

Unlike the single quote marks the double quote marks are applicable when the name contains a variable:

```
cd "$HOME/ISO&Emulator"
```

Comment: The same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952315/a-strange-path-to-the-folder).

Answer (score 5):

Since this isn't a command-line-only system and a graphical [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) is installed, you should know about another way to use files and directories from the terminal whose  names require quoting or are otherwise cumbrersome to type: **Drag the folder icon from your file browser into the terminal window.** On you system the file browser is Nautilus, but this works with nearly all file browsers. This pastes the full path of the file or directory whose icon you dragged *with correct quoting automatically applied*.

This isn't a full substitute for knowing how to quote pathnames (or, really, any text) yourself using the techniques [pa4080 describes](https://askubuntu.com/a/961736/22949), but it's extremely useful, can save you a lot of time, and if you're not comfortable with when and how to quote using `\`, in most graphical terminal emulators that's the form of quoting that is automatically applied when you do this, so it will demonstrate it to you. (In some, `'` `'` are used.)

Unless you've changed it, the shell you get when you open a terminal window or log on in a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) is [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)). The purpose of quoting in any shell is to tell the shell not to treat certain characters specially. You may want to read [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

When you quote manually, I suggest you prefer [the `'` `'` (single quotes) form](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes),  since it's the simplest and easiest way to quote more than a few characters of text. If what you want to quote doesn't itself contain a `'` character then you can *always* enclose it in single quotes, because the only character with special meaning after `'` begins quoting is the subsequent `'` that ends quoting.

---

Finally, you may be wondering *what happened* when you had an unquoted `&` in your command.

This treated what came before it (`cd ISO`) as one command, [ran it asynchronously](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) in the background, and treated what came after it (`Emulator`) as a second command to run as well (in the foreground, since it had no `&` after it).

1. `[1] 1635` reported the [background job](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) had started (it was job 1, and its [process ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) happened to be 1635).
2. `bash: Emulator: command not found` reported there was no command called `Emulator`.
3. The message `bash: cd: ISO: No such file or directory` arrived from the background job to report there was no `ISO` directory to change to.
4. `[1]+  Exit 1` reported job 1 had finished.

Comment: Here is an illustration of the drag and drop method: [CLI path to ftp network connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/876425/566421).