# Why does mkdir fail (no such file or directory) in a script with BIN_DIR="~/bin/"?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, home-directory, mkdir

Why does the mkdir command fail with: "No such file or directory"?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

BIN_DIR="~/bin/"

if [ ! -d "$BIN_DIR" ]; then
  mkdir "$BIN_DIR"
fi
```

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is produced because the tilde `~` is quoted, as described in Zanna's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/977359/566421). If you want to use the `~`, the relevant part of the script should be:

```sh
BIN_DIR=~/bin/
```

If for [whatever reason](https://askubuntu.com/a/961736/566421) you want to quote the string, you can use the environment variable `$HOME`:

```
BIN_DIR="$HOME/bin/"
```

In my opinion the second approach is better practice.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `~` in scripts. it works in exactly the same way as in the command line. The problem is that quoting blocks tilde expansion as explained in [Zanna's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/977359/85695).

Comment: @terdon, I'm agree. But I haven't told there is something wrong, but it is a better idea, because you should pay less attention.

Comment: But there's absolutely no difference between the command line and a script here. The fact that this is in a script is completely irrelevant, you would have exactly the same error in the commandline. The issue is the quoting, not that it's in a script.

Comment: While that's totally true it's also right that using `$HOME` in scripts is a good idea.

Comment: @pa4080 Can you add an explanation of *why* you think it's better to expand `$HOME` than to use tilde expansion? The only explanation you've given is to say, "it is a better idea, because you should pay less attention." I have no idea what that means. Can you expound on it in an edit? Without it, there is nothing supporting your answer, so surely it belongs in it. Tilde expansion has been required by POSIX for [quite a while now](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006) *and* the script's hashbang line is `#!/bin/bash` so I suppose portability isn't the reason.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I've updated the answer with what I had in mind. Sorry for the late update but I had some work to do.

Comment: Thanks--your edit has somewhat improved this answer. But I'm not sure the reasoning you've given stands up to scrutiny. `~/bin` is as practical as `$HOME/bin`. Really *more*--it's what most people already use interactively. You say quoting is different or is used differently in scripts, which seems obviously false to me, but maybe you could explain it in another edit? *Most importantly, using `$HOME` does not make attention unnecessary!* Filenames often contain `"`, `$`, or `\``. Whether `$HOME` or `~` is used, it's *always* necessary to consider if and *how* to quote the rest of the path.

Comment: @EliahKagan, In an attempt to clarify what I mean, I've edited the answer one more time: )

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what you mean by "In the scripts things are back, for different reasons in most cases we want to quote the strings that we assign as variable's values." What does "things are back" mean? What are the "different reasons"?

Comment: @EliahKagan, I think I found what is the problem with this answer. Something more, I found that, I spent more effort to explain what I mean instead of just saying it. Thank you for the criticism and best regards!

Answer (score 23):

It doesn't work because `~` is quoted. [Double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) `"` suppress [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion). There is no directory with the literal name `~/bin`. As explained in [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> Tilde Expansion
>
> If a word begins with an **unquoted** tilde character  (`~'),  all  of  the
>          characters  preceding  the  first unquoted slash (or all characters, if
>          there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none  of
>          the  characters  in  the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the
>          tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login  name.
>          If  this  login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the
>          value of the shell parameter HOME.  If HOME is unset, the  home  directory  of  the  user executing the shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home  directory  associated
>          with the specified login name.

**You can remove the quotes**, since `~` is the only character in the path `~/bin` that will cause the shell to perform an expansion, and we want the expansion in this case. The shell [won't perform](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41205475#41205475) any further expansions on the result of tilde expansion, [at least in Bash 4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397696/11938), which all current or remotely recent releases of Ubuntu [have](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bash&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). So even if your home directory contains unusual characters like spaces, it's okay.

**Or you can use `$HOME` instead** of `~`, because [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is not suppressed by double quotes, only by [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes). The double quotes *do* ensure that the expanded value is not itself subject to any further expansions, so [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) or [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) will not occur. So `$HOME` works even with strangely named home directories, too, so long as you keep the double quotes.

Comment: According to this statement *"parameter expansion is not suppressed by double quotes, only by single quotes"*: the output of `cd '~'` is `-bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @pa4080 Expansion of `~` is not part of parameter expansion.