# Creating a Wine Prefix

Tags: wine, winetricks

I ran the command `export WINEPREFIX="~/.wine_custom"` in an attempt to make a wineprefix to get a game working. However, no output was made, so I assumed it worked. However, when I used the next command, `winetricks corefonts dxvk dotnet472`, I got this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Your version of wine  is no longer supported upstream. You should upgrade to 5.x
------------------------------------------------------
Executing mkdir -p ~
ls: cannot access '~/.wine_custom/drive_c': No such file or directory
grep: ~/.wine_custom/*.reg: No such file or directory
------------------------------------------------------
WINEPREFIX INFO:
Drive C: 

Registry info:
~/.wine_custom/*.reg:
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
warning: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "wine: invalid directory ~/.wine_custom in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path" 
------------------------------------------------------
```

What did I do wrong?

Edit: After a bit of experimentation, I got the first command to work. but I now have a different output with the 2nd command.

### Executing mkdir -p /home/username
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/username’: Permission denied

### warning: Note: command mkdir -p /home/username returned status 1. Aborting.

How do I give permission to the command?

Comment: have you tried to assign a fullpath "WINEPREFIX=/home/username/.winepath"  wineprefix global envionment variable ?

Comment: `~` doesn't expand when quoted - see related [Why does mkdir fail (no such file or directory) in a script with BIN_DIR="~/bin/"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977354/why-does-mkdir-fail-no-such-file-or-directory-in-a-script-with-bin-dir-bin)

Comment: Try this. `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine_custom" wine wineboot` and then `winetricks corefonts dxvk dotnet472`.

Comment: @Liso I got this output from the first command.

`wine: chdir to /home/username/.wine_custom : No such file or directory`